# How can I save bread from mildew?

Tags: food-safety, bread, food-science

Because of mildew we waste breads. How can I save breads from mildew?[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can eat it quickly, or you can freeze it. Keeping it in the fridge is sometimes an option but for bread that is to be eaten as bread (rather than toasted) you end up with stale/dry bread (safe but a poor texture).

Warm, humid rooms encourage bread to go bad more quickly, so you can sometimes get slightly better life by choosing your storage location carefully.